# dynamically building up call to jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to do the following to build up the call to a jquery plugin

```
jQuery("#wrapper").myPLugin({
    direction: direction,
    switch myOption
    {
        case "small":
        items:10,

        case "big":
        items:25,

    }
    switch otherOption
    {
        case "small":
            prev: {
            button: buttonPrev,
            key: "left"
        },

        case "big":
            prev: {
            button: buttonPrev,
            key: "left"
        },

    }
    pagination: ".paginationHolder"
});
```

Obviously this does not work , but what is the best way to these kind of buildups, is there a general method to dynamically build up a call to jQuery plugins like this

Comment: What do you mean by ""dynamically build up a call to jQuery plugins""?

Comment: As you can see above, i want to have switch and if statements etc and based on that pass a different option , so ( in above example )do i pass 10 or 25 items to this specific plugin call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

the ternary operator is your friend

```
condition ? trueResult : falseResult
```

so in your case that could be

```
jQuery("#wrapper").myPLugin({
    direction: direction,
    items: myOption == "small" ? 10 : myOption == "big" ? 25 : 0, // or some default value
    prev: otherOption == "samll" ? {button: prevButton, key: 'left'} : otherOption == "big" ? {button: prevButton, key: 'left'} : null,
    pagination: ".paginationHolder"
});
```

## Option 2

Another option is to build up your object outside of the call, after all javascript objects are totally dynamicallly typed:

```
var setup = new object();
setup.direction = "foo";
switch(myOption){
  case "small":
    setup.items = 10;
    break;
  case "big":
    setup.items = 25;
    break;
}
switch(otherOption){
  case "small":
    setup.prev = {button: prevButton, key: 'left'};
    break;
  case "big":
    setup.prev = {button: prevButton, key: 'left'};
    break;
}
setup.pagination =".paginationHolder"

jQuery("#wrapper").myPLugin(setup);
```

Comment: edited it with otherOption, how would i build that set-up up dynamically   setup.??

Comment: @nokiko - see updated answer. If this is getting complex use option 2.